# Passing an object into a function (Object defined in Main)

Tags: c++, object

How do I pass an object, defined in Main, into a function?

My `main` function looks like this:

```
// Initialising the players
Player Joe;
Player Sid;

Joe.setPlayerName("Joe");
Sid.setPlayerName("Sid");

Joe.setPercentage(71);
Sid.setPercentage(73);

Joe.setTotal(501);
Sid.setTotal(501);

Joe.setThrows(0);
Sid.setThrows(0);


// Starts Joe's turn (and the game)
turn(Joe);
```

Within another function called `calculateTotal`, I have the following section of code:

```
else if (potentialTotal < 2 && potentialTotal != 0)
{
    potentialTotal = total; // Total remains the same
    player.setThrows(0); // Resets their throws

    // Switch player's turn
    if (player.getPlayerName() == "Joe")
    {
        turn(Sid);
    }
    else if (player.getPlayerName() == "Sid")
    {
        turn(Joe);
    }
}
```

The problem is the `Sid` in `turn(Sid)` as well as `Joe` in `turn(Joe)` do not work, this is because they are declared in the `main` and not the `calculateTotal` function.

I have passed the `Player` object through as seen in `calculateTotal` function - `player.getPlayerName()` for example, but if I put `turn(player)`, this would call `turn(Joe)` as he goes first which is not what I need, I need it to switch to `Sid`.

The functions in the program.

```
void turn(Player& player);

void bullseye(Player& player);

void singleThrow(int requiredValue, Player& player);
void doubleThrow(int dartThrow, Player& player);
void trebleThrow(int dartThrow, Player& player);

void calculateTotal(Player& player);
```

This is the error:

```
1>f:\abertay\programming\coursework\coursework\source.cpp(149): error C2065:    'Sid' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\abertay\programming\coursework\coursework\source.cpp(153): error C2065: 'Joe' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\abertay\programming\coursework\coursework\source.cpp(169): error C2065: 'Sid' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\abertay\programming\coursework\coursework\source.cpp(173): error C2065: 'Joe' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: [mcve] please. I think your code is small enough for it all to fit here.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to rethink your design. When you need objects in `main`, you usually pass them to another function. However, it sounds like these objects are sort of 'global'. Perhaps consider an object-oriented approach where `Joe` and `Sid` are member variables of some larger object. Then you pass that object (instead of all the variables separately) to functions.

Comment: It would help to see your declaration of the calculations function. I suspect you need to use a pointer to the player object as an argument instead of passing the player object itself.

Comment: I have added in the declarations for every function to try and help out.

Answer (score 0):

**Pass a Reference**

If you create your objects in the main and don't want copies of the objects (which appear to be the case), pass a *reference* to the objects in your `main` to your `calculations` function:

```
void calculations(Player& Joe, Player& Sid)
{
    //...
    else if (potentialTotal < 2 && potentialTotal != 0)
    {
        potentialTotal = total; // Total remains the same
        player.setThrows(0); // Resets their throws

        // Switch player's turn
        if (player.getPlayerName() == "Joe")
        {
            turn(Sid);
        }
        else if (player.getPlayerName() == "Sid")
        {
            turn(Joe);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

If you are not familiar, a reference is simply another name for an object, it will not copy your `Player` objects, instead, `calculations` function will refer to the objects in the `main` function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have an issue with this. I already have `Player& player` passing into that function, if I add `Joe` and `Sid` it conflicts with other functions that rely on calling the `calculateTotal` function as I'm not sure what else to pass in with `calculateTotal(player)`.